# How to find input string first characters length is 4?

Tags: java

How to find below input string length 4 or not. I want to check - symbol before characters length 4 or not.

```
**2020-08-09**
```

Comment: I'm... I'm not sure what to do here. Can you please explain what's going on ?

Comment: i want to check before - symbol characters length 4 or not

Comment: i would like to check year characters length 4 or not

Comment: You could split at the `-` , get the first element of the array, replace ** by nothing and check the length...

Comment: Ummm ... that looks like a date.  You should probably be using one of the Java SE data parsers than trying to "string bash" the date to extract the year ... if that is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
boolean isLength4 = "**2020-08-09**".replace("**","").indexOf("-") == 4;

System.out.printl(isLength4);
```

Prints

```
true
```

A better approach for handling dates is to use classes from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

- `[]` ignore characters between braces
- `yyyy-MM-dd`  numeric year, month and day.  Many options available.

```
String dateString = "**2020-08-09**";

try {
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("[**]yyyy-MM-dd[**]"));
    System.out.println(ld);
} catch (DateTimeParseException pe) {
    System.out.println("Invalid date");
}
```

Prints

```
2020-08-09
```

The output can be altered by using another [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] dateSplit = "2020-08-09".split("-");
if (dateSplit[0].length() == 4) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

or

```
return "2020-08-09".split("-")[0].length() == 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Validation, Using REGEX**

We are checking that the date stamp has expected format, including that year har four digits - meaning that year has length 4.

**Used regex:**

```
boolean isDateStampValid = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\b").matcher(input).find();
```

**Regex in context:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "**2020-08-09**";
    boolean isDateStampValid = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\b").matcher(input).find();
    System.out.println("Is date stamp in format yyyy-MM-dd: " + isDateStampValid);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Is date stamp in format yyyy-MM-dd: true
```